# Django / Docker, manage a million images and many large files

Tags: django, docker, dev-to-production

The project I am working on relies on many static files. I am looking for guidance on how to deal with the situation. First I will explain the situation, then I will ask my questions.

## The Situation

The files that need management:

- Roughly 1.5 million `.bmp` images, about 100 GB
- Roughly 100 `.h5` files, 250 MB each, about 25 GB

**bmp files**

The images are part of an image library, the user can filter trough them based on multiple different kinds of meta data. The meta data is spread out over multiple Models such as: Printer, PaperType, and Source.

In development the images sit in the `static` folder of the Django project, this works fine for now.

**h5 files**

Each app has its own set of `.h5` files. They are used to inspect user generated images. Results of this inspection are stored in the database, the image itself is stored on disc.

## Moving to production

Now that you know a bit about the problem it is time to ask my questions.

Please note that I have never pushed a Django project to production before. I am also new to Docker.

### Docker

The project needs to be deployed on multiple machines, to make this more easy I decided to use Docker. I managed to build the Image and run the Container without the `.bmp` and `.h5` files. So far so good!

How do I deal with the `.h5` files? It does not seem like a good idea to build an Image that is 25 GB in size. Is there a way to download the `.h5` file at a later point in time? As in building a Docker Image that only contains the code and downloads the `.h5` files later.

### Image files

I'm pretty sure that Django's `collectstatic` command is not meant for moving the amount of images the project uses. I'm thinking along the lines of directly uploading the images to some kind of image server.

If there are specialized image servers I would love to hear your suggestions.

Comment: Are you deploying this on your own server, a dedicated hosted server (e.g., Rackspace) or on a cloud service (e.g., AWS)? If you are using AWS (and I assume similar things available with Azure, etc.) then seriously consider using S3 to host these files. You could easily have two different buckets for Dev. vs. Prod., but the storage costs are relatively low and for static or rarely updated files, it can work very, very well.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact This will be hosted on private servers due to regulations, cloud services like AWS/Azure/etc. are not allowed. We will be running Ubuntu Server.